# The semigroup of vector bundles by gluing of contractible patches

Tags: homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

Assume $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two contractible compact manifolds with boundary and that $\partial M_1 = \partial M_2 = \Omega$. Fix a homeomorphism between the boundaries and consider $X = M_1 \sharp M_2$ the space obtained by gluing those two manifolds by their boundaries. The example I have in mind is the sphere $S^2$ given by union of two closed disks glued by their boundaries.

Let $VO(X)$ be the abelian semigroup given by all real vector bundles over $X$ with fiberwise direct sum and $VU(X)$ the corresponding semigroup for complex vector bundles.

> **Question 1:** Can the structure of $VO(X)$, resp. $VU(X)$, be explicitly described?

Let $E \to X$ is one such bundle, assume it is $n$-dimensional. $E$ restricted to the interior of $M_1$ is trivial and the same holds for the restriction to $M_2$. The gluing of the fibers over $\partial M_1$ will be given by a map $\Omega \to O(n)$, resp. $\Omega \to U(n)$. It seems intuitive that homotopy-equivalent maps induce equivalent vector bundles and thus we have maps
$$
    [\Omega, O(n)] \to VO(X) \quad \mbox{and} \quad [\Omega, U(n)] \to VU(X)
$$
(Here [X, Y] denotes the space of cont. maps $X \to Y$ up to homotopy)

If we define the abelian semigroups $WO(\Omega)$ and $WU(\Omega)$ by taking
$$
    WO(\Omega) = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} [\Omega, O(n)]
    \quad \mbox{and} \quad
    WU(\Omega) = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} [\Omega, U(n)].
$$
with addition given by direct sums, i.e. for $\phi_1: \Omega \to O(n_1)$ and $\phi_2: \Omega \to O(n_2)$ we have $\phi_1 + \phi_2:= \phi_1 \oplus \phi_2: \Omega \to O(n_1) \oplus O(n_2) \subset O(n_1 + n_2)$

> **Question2:** Does the natural map induce homomorphisms of abelian semigroups $$    WO(\Omega) \to VO(X)    \quad \mbox{and} \quad  WU(\Omega) \to VU(X). $$ If so, are those maps surjective?

I will rule out the possibility of those maps being injective, at least in the real case, since $O(1) = \{+1,-1\}$ but the only real $1$-dimensional bundle over the sphere $S^2$ is the trivial one.

(I am a newcomer to K-theory, just trying to grasp a few basic concepts. Pointers are welcome)

Comment: Forget the semi-group issue and just consider Assume 1
M
1
 and 2
M
2
 are two contractible compact manifolds with boundary and that ∂1=∂2=Ω

. Fix a homeomorphism between the boundaries and consider =1♯2

 the space obtained by gluing those two manifolds by their boundaries. The example I have in mind is the sphere 2
S
2
 given by union of two closed disks glued by their boundaries. Where is written  that there is a corresponding bundle over the union of U and V for closed U and V with boundary or portion thereof

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you have almost defined the $K$-theory of a group, the Grothendieck completion of $VO(X)$ is $K(X)$, the Chern character induces an isomorphism between $K(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow H^{2*}(X,\mathbb{Q})$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_K-theory